# Problema com o JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Estou com um problema em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo utilizando o springboot juntamente com o JPA Hibernate. Eu não sou tão experiente utilizando eles, então perdão antecipadamente.

Vamos logo ao problema: Eu tenho 2 tabelas atualmente, uma com o nome `Documento` e outra com o nome `Bgo`. A tabela Documento é a tabela pai e a Bgo a tabela filho, portanto há uma relação entre elas de *OneToOne* em que a chave primária de Documento vai para Bgo como chave estrangeira, E AO MESMO TEMPO, eu quero que essa chave estrangeira seja primária, ou seja, o Id da tabela Bgo vai ser O MESMO ID da tabela Documento.

Por exemplo: Eu quero que quando eu criar um novo Documento juntamente com o Bgo na mesma requisição *POST*, o id de Documento vai ser algo do tipo id_documento = 1, e eu quero que o de Bgo também seja id_documento = 1.
Eu literalmente quero que o Id de Bgo seja o Id que vem da tabela Documento.

Vai ser algo desse tipo:

[image: Modelo do banco de dados]

Lembrando que eu só quero que Bgo possa ter o MESMO id de Documento, o Bgo não tem seu id próprio tipo "id_bgo", o id de Bgo é literalmente o de id de Documento.

Vou mostrar o código:

Entidade pai Documento:

```
package com.testing.testing.models;


import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
public class Document  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id_document;

private int num_document;

private Date date;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "document", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Bgo bgo;

public Document() {
}

public Document(Bgo bgo) {
    this.id_document = bgo.getId_document();
    this.bgo = bgo;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Bgo getBgo() {
    return bgo;
}

public void setBgo(Bgo bgo) {
    this.bgo = bgo;
}

public long getId_document() {
    return id_document;
}

public void setId_document(long id_document) {
    this.id_document = id_document;
}

public int getNum_document() {
    return num_document;
}

public void setNum_document(int num_document) {
    this.num_document = num_document;
}


}
```

Entidade filho Bgo:

```
package com.testing.testing.models;



import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;


@Entity
public class Bgo {


@Id
private long id_document;

private String name_bgo;

private int num_bgo;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_document", referencedColumnName = "id_document")
private Document document;

public Bgo() {
    
}

public Bgo(Document document) {
    this.id_document = document.getId_document();
    this.document = document;
}

public long getId_document() {
    return id_document;
}

public void setId_document(long id_document) {
    this.id_document = id_document;
}

public String getName_bgo() {
    return name_bgo;
}

public void setName_bgo(String name_bgo) {
    this.name_bgo = name_bgo;
}

public int getNum_bgo() {
    return num_bgo;
}

public void setNum_bgo(int num_bgo) {
    this.num_bgo = num_bgo;
}

public Document getDocument() {
    return document;
}

public void setDocument(Document document) {
    this.document = document;
}




}
```

Perceba que eu utilizei esse "PrimaryKeyJoinColumn" na tabela de Bgo, porque eu tinha visto em um fórum que esse era um jeito de fazer com que a tabela que está recebendo a chave estrangeira, recebesse ao mesmo tempo como chave primária também, ou seja, será chave primária e estrangeira ao mesmo tempo, como tem no modelo do banco. Mas eu não sei se essa é a melhor forma de se alcançar o meu objetivo, então qualquer ajuda será bem vinda, já que não sou tão experiente com o JPA Hibernate.

Aí eu tenho o Controller de Documento:

```
package com.testing.testing.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import com.testing.testing.models.Document;
import com.testing.testing.repository.DocumentRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/document")
public class DocumentController {

@Autowired
DocumentRepository documentRepository;


@GetMapping
public List<Document> listDocument() {
    return documentRepository.findAll();
}

@PostMapping
public Document createDocument(@RequestBody Document document) {
    return documentRepository.save(document);
}
}
```

Controller do Bgo:

```
package com.testing.testing.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import com.testing.testing.models.Bgo;
import com.testing.testing.repository.BgoRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/bgo")
public class BgoController {

@Autowired
BgoRepository bgoRepository;

@GetMapping
public List<Bgo> listBgo() {
    return bgoRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

Repositório JPA de Bgo:

```
package com.testing.testing.repository;

import com.testing.testing.models.Bgo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BgoRepository extends JpaRepository<Bgo, Long> {

}
```

Do Documento:

```
package com.testing.testing.repository;

import com.testing.testing.models.Document;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Long> {

}
```

A imagem do problema:

[image: Imagem da requisição POST]

Perceba que eu estou criando as 2 entidades em um só endpoint, eu estou passando os atributos de documento(lembrando que o id de documento é auto incrementado), e depois eu passo o objeto Bgo e dentro os seus atributos. Mas se você perceber, não aconteceu o que eu queria, o id de documento é "id_document=1", mas o de de Bgo é "id_document=0", e eu queria que o id de Bgo fosse justamente o id de Documento.

E quando eu listo o Bgo, acontece a mesma coisa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer o que eu estou tentando? Se não for, há uma outra maneira de eu realizar isso. Quem puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito, não aguento mais ficar tanto tempo nisso sem conseguir resolver.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: O que seria Bgo? talvez você possa resolver com uma classe @Embedded, ou retornar o id que precisa inserir na Bgo enquanto está com EntityManager de forma gerenciável.

Comment: Suas tabelas está realmente com o mesmo nome que está no diagrama?

Comment: Sim, estão, é que no código tá em inglês, só que eu esqueci de trocar o nome das tabelas pra inglês na modelagem também.

Comment: Mas o nome não importa tanto agora, só estou completamente sem saber o que fazer pra alcançar o que eu quero
@JonyLima

Comment: @AndréMartins, poderia me mostrar como eu faria isso? Eu não sou tão experiente no Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a anotação @MapsId do JPA para dizer que a chave estrangeira de uma entidade está associada como a chave primária de outra e antes de inserir terá que setar o document para o seu bgo.

Bgo:

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id_document", referencedColumnName = "id_document")
@MapsId
@OneToOne
private Document document;
```

DocumentController:

```
@PostMapping
public Document createDocument(@RequestBody Document document) {
    document.getBgo().setDocument(document);
    return documentRepository.save(document);
}
```

Você também pode mapear seu Bgo da seguinte forma e não será necessário mais criar o campo id_document no bgo:

```
@Entity
public class Bgo implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String name_bgo;
  private int num_bgo;

  @Id
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_document", referencedColumnName = "id_document")
  private Document document;

  public Bgo() {

  }

  public Bgo(Document document) {
      this.document = document;
  }

  public String getName_bgo() {
      return name_bgo;
  }

  public void setName_bgo(String name_bgo) {
      this.name_bgo = name_bgo;
  }

  public int getNum_bgo() {
      return num_bgo;
  }

  public void setNum_bgo(int num_bgo) {
      this.num_bgo = num_bgo;
  }

  public Document getDocument() {
      return document;
  }

  public void setDocument(Document document) {
      this.document = document;
  }

}
```

Comment: Você é o cara! Deu certo aqui! Fui no banco de dados e vi que o id de Bgo é justamente o id de Document! Eu só tive que colocar um JsonIgnore em cima do `private Document document`, porque estava retornando a mesma coisa várias vezes.
Valeu, mano!

Comment: se você puder me recomendar bons lugares de estudo pro java, eu agradeço muito.